# Populate DIV dynamically from external Javascript using data from database

Tags: javascript, database, external

I am developing a plugin for displaying a list of images in others' website. I intend to provide them only one url (probably a JS link) which they need to embed in their site so that they will see those images. These list of images would come from my database. Can you please tell me if such a functionality is achievable using Javascript?

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: use an iframe as the embed code and then link that iframe to a normal webpage that you control.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client only and for those security reasons you cannot and should not connect to a database from js. What you can do is use a webpage to produce those images and use your script to inject the page into their sites. You can do this via an iframe or an object tag.